# During Webix datatable sub-column edit how to modify the nested JSON data accordingly?

Tags: json, datatable, webix

In my Webix datatable, I have multiple columns under one column header by colspan.
I populate the table by a JSON data and that JSON data is having an Array structure to populate those sub-columns.

I observe that when I edit a cell under those columns, it is adding one extra field to the data set and not updating the exact nested object.

Let's say for a specific row, the data set looks like below before editing :

```
obj = {"No":"1","Name":"Justine","place":[{"address":"address1","name":"name1"}],"id":1512587573601}
```

Now if I edit the adress field to 'address_new', then it is getting added as a separate key (as place_address) to the data set as below :

```
obj = {"No":"1","Name":"Justine","place":[{"address":"address1","name":"name1"}],"id":1512587573601,"place_address":"address_new"}
```

Here is the snippet: https://webix.com/snippet/7882897c

How can this be solved?

Thanks.

Comment: I have been able to get a solution of the problem which somehow meets my requirement. The snippet is here : https://webix.com/snippet/13876a1c I am manipulating the table object directly in the custom cell event and in $init assigning default values to the cells to retain their existing value when clicked. I am sure there is a better solution of this problem, if anyone of you knows that , kindly provide. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are doing lot of work, you can do the same by simple steps:
https://webix.com/snippet/c60a1b45

Comment: Thanks, this is an easier solution indeed. However, when I click on the cells, their existing values are disappearing, how can I address that if I need to add something to the existing value ?

Comment: You can do the same by overriding the onItemDblClick: https://webix.com/snippet/5b83757d

Comment: feel free to ask in case you still face any issues.

Comment: It is working very fine. However, I facing a small weird  problem that is if I delete the value from the cell and click outside, expectedly it should show empty cell in it. But this is working very strangely, after deleting the value if I click on elsewhere , then it is still showing old value, but if I click on another empty cell then it is taking effect. I am sorry I can not provide a snippet for this. Your one is working perfectly fine. The only difference that I have is I am having editaction as 'click' instead of 'dblclick' . Can you suggest any idea why it may happen?

Comment: Actually I have given only a to-the-point snippet of the requirement, in actual it is little more complex. Let me see if I can reproduce it and provide that. Thanks nevertheless.